# unknown properties of angular 6 <table mat-table>

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

This is no duplicate of any other questions about angular material table with this context. All these others refere to angular 2-5, not 6

I'm getting this exception:

> Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'table'.
>   ("
>
> ][dataSource]="dataSource" 
>   class="mat-elevation-z8">

If I remove [dataSource], the exception is the same, with the next specific directive.

**HTML**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource"  class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="ID">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Id </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.ID}} </td>
    </ng-container>

   <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
   <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import {
    MatTabsModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatTableModule
} from "@angular/material";

@NgModule({
   declarations: [AppComponent, ProjektuebersichtComponent],
   imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     HazardRatingVerwaltungModule,
     AppRoutingModule,
     BrowserAnimationsModule,
     ServicesModule,
     MatTabsModule,
     MatCardModule,
     MatInputModule,
     MatTableModule
   ],
   providers: [],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })
 export class AppModule {}
```

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.5",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
```

It should work basically. But it doesn't. I have all dependencies updated and I imported the needed MatTableModule. The code is from material.angular.io. I don't know what is wrong there.

Comment: try changing <table> to <mat-table>.

Comment: this is angular 5... this doesn't work with 6

Comment: Are you sure that you imported `MatTableModule` in the right module?

Comment: @enf0rcer according to [the documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview), the OP's syntax is the right one. According to the doc, `mat-table` should be placed as attribute of the `<table>` element.

Comment: Are you using lazy Module concept..??

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle maybe they recently changed the api, and TS needs to update. It used to be documented to be used as element only selector, meaning <mat-table>.

Answer (score 1):

you do not need to use the tag `table`. just use

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource"  class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="ID">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Id </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.ID}} </td>
    </ng-container>

   <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
   <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</mat-table>
```

and it should work